# overlooping in C#

Tags: c#, loops, sleep

I am going to create a system service in C#.

In the onstart section I would like to loop every 30 seconds and query a mysql database.  If numrows are greater than 0 I will process some faxes using the faxcom library.

My question is: Would looping every 30 seconds exhaust the program/computer?  What would be the best function/method to use for the loop and sleep?  Do you have any example code for the loop and sleep?

Comment: what's *overlooping*?

Comment: @TheScrumMeister - One assumes from context that it is the practice of looping too much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `Thread.Sleep()` would be a bad solution, because even while sleeping your thread is active. Use `Timer` class instead and handle its `Elapsed` event.

[This article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=415982) examines different ways to tackle the periodical execution of your service.

Here is what your OnStart method might look like:

```
using System.Timers; 

private timer = new Timer();

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
 timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
 timer.Interval = 30000; // every 30 seconds
 timer.Enabled = true;
}

Private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   // Execute your code here
}
```

Comment: Cool.  Do I need to do anything with the timer when the system service is stopped?  BTW.. This is a cool site!

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if you stop your timer be setting the .Enabled property to false :) You are welcome, consider upvoting answers and tagging them as a reply if you found them useful! That helps the community to keep track and increases somebody's rating :)

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use looping constructs for such a thing.

I would use one of the [timer controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) in the BCL and set it to fire every 30 seconds.

As for the question of if this is "too much", the answer entirely depends on the amount of work being done and the load it generates.

Answer (score 1):

No, you would not be using the CPU, because sleeping threads are not scheduled for execution until their sleep time expires. Use [Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) to make the current thread sleep for timeout miliseconds. Something like:

```
while(!stop) // boolean variable to indicate when to stop the service.
{
    Thread.Sleep(30000);
    // do work
}
```

You will, of course, need to run this on a separate thread, otherwise you will block the main thread.

Comment: This is actually not a nice solution for periodical execution, especially taking into account that the sleep time here will be 30000 msec. Look at this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using `System.Timers.Timer` in your case solely because you are writing a Windows Service.  While you *can* use it, you won't have a GUI available and therefore don't need anything that this timer would expose as if you were using a GUI (it inherits from `System.ComponentModel.Component` for this reason).  It's pretty simple 
to use.